# Instantly updating UI with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a button that triggers the opening of a menu. My initial idea was to set the state on the button click, but what's happening is that the very first click has no effect on the state or class. The change is triggered on the second and subsequent clicks.

I'm understanding *why* the state of the visibility isn't working (because setState is an asynchronous method) but how do I get it to change from the initial click?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Social extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // class of the div that will change
    this.menuVisibility = "social--icons_cntr--close"; 

    // managing the visibility of the menu items
    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };

    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseDown(e) {
    // if the state is visible, use the open class
    if (this.state.visible === true) {
      this.menuVisibility = "social--icons_cntr--open";
    } 
    // if the state is not visible use the close class
    else if (this.state.visible === false) {
      this.menuVisibility = "social--icons_cntr--close";
    }
    // call the the toggleMenu method
    this.toggleMenu();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    this.setState(
      { visible: !this.state.visible })

    console.log("visibility: ", this.state.visible);
    console.log("menuvis ", this.menuVisibility);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="social--cntr">
        <div className={this.menuVisibility}>
          <a className="social--icons-link" href="#">[X]</a>
        </div>
        <div className="social--btn-click social--btn-open"
          onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
          <span>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding that `setState`  is **async** then the structure of this should change. Bind the classes to conditional statements based on state e.g.

```
<div className={{ (this.state.visible ? 'social--icons_cntr--open' : 'social--icons_cntr--close') }}>
```

and then in your `onMouseDown` function just have `this.setState({{ !visible }})` . This way the components will be bound to state and update following the lifecycle methods i.e. on `ComponentDidUpdate`

Answer (score 1):

`setState` has a second parameter of a callback method. You could have your code there so that the console logged value is updated.

```
toggleMenu() {
  this.setState(
    { visible: !this.state.visible },
    () => {
      console.log("visibility: ", this.state.visible);
      console.log("menuvis ", this.menuVisibility);
    })
}
```

But, in this case, where you want to update the view, it's better just to use the state values in the JSX template and update the view that way.

You could in the template use the following syntax:

```
<div className={this.state.visible ? 'social--icons_cntr--close' : 'social--icons_cntr--open'} >
```

Find the StackBlitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nszfds

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of `setState` being asynchronous, but because of a minor `logical error`.
You are first checking the state to be true or false and then only changing the state.
If it was reverse then it would have worked.

And yes `setState` is `asynchronous` and has a call back function as its second parameter to do things after setting the state.

You can use the below code,

```
handleMouseDown(e) {

  this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible },()=>{
    // if the state is visible, use the open class
    if (this.state.visible === true) {
      this.menuVisibility = "social--icons_cntr--open";
    } 
    // if the state is not visible use the close class
    else if (this.state.visible === false) {
      this.menuVisibility = "social--icons_cntr--close";
    }
    })
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```